# DocumentFormat.OpenXml in Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mono, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a basic C# application where Open XML SDK is used. I want to make it run in my Nginx & Ubuntu & DigitalOcean server.

The application compiles and works well in Windows, and **my Mac with mono**. Then, I installed mono in the Ubuntu server, and scp the .exe file to the server, and run `mono ConsoleApplication2.exe`, it returned the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
 at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
  at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30850482/702977), it seems that the problem comes from the version of `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`. But how could I install its right version in a Ubuntu server?

Could anyone help?

**Update 1:** Then, I tried to install Open XML SDK `2.6.1`, but there is [no makefile](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fb8c7a08-cc65-415a-9783-8023c2933187/install-open-xml-sdk-in-a-ubuntu-server?forum=oxmlsdk). Otherwise, for Open XML SDK `2.5`, I don't know where to find a release distribution.

**Update 2:** I should have tried `build.open-xml-sdk.sh`... I tried to run it in the server, but it gives [an error](http://pastebin.com/y3p3UDKy). Does anyone know what's wrong here?

**Update 3:** I uninstalled mono, and followed [this link](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-apache24-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

mono was re-installed successfully. Then I tried `build.open-xml-sdk.sh` again, but it returned [the same error](http://pastebin.com/y3p3UDKy).

**Update 4:** Following the comment of ZagNut, I tried to add DLLs to GAC. I noticed two things:

1) I downloaded the source code and generated `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` and `System.IO.Packaging.dll`, they made my program compile well in Visual Studio. However, when i tried to add them to GAC by `gacutil`, it tells me they need a **strong name**.

2) Then I tried to add **strong name** to them by following [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/341645/Referenced-assembly-does-not-have-a-strong-name), I realised that the new 2 dlls could not work correctly in Visual Studio anymore:

[image]

Comment: have you seen this "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/blob/vNext/build.open-xml-sdk.sh"?

Comment: I tried `build.open-xml-sdk.sh`, but it returned an error. Please see my OP...

Comment: Sorry, the link you gave is invalid...

Comment: pardon. writing from cellphone. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: Please see my **Update 3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the binaries you need alongside your application executable.

for the binaries, you can build it yourself:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

or download from below and just extract the binaries using [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) or installing it and finding them.

2.0: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

2.5: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

Comment: Thanks for links for `2.0` and `2.5`... but I am talking about installing them in Ubuntu server, rather than in Windows...

Comment: ok extract the binaries and add them to the GAC: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/assemblies-and-the-gac/

Comment: Please see my **Update 4**

Comment: ugh.  and it doesn't work if you just drop the dlls in the directory next to the executable?  if Mono works like .NET, it will automatically search there for the dlls.  If it works, you could then explicitly reference them in your project and they should always be included with your builds.  you won't have to string name them, then.

Comment: See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx) especially regarding probing.  It should look in the same directory as the executing assembly for those dlls.

Comment: Indeed, it works... Namely, 1) download and install the `.msi` from Microsoft site, and copy `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` to the Ubuntu server; 2) build `Sample.exe` with the same dll in Visual Studio, and copy `Sample.exe` to the Ubuntu server, in the SAME folder as the previous dll; 3) `mono Sample.exe` works.